# PHP socket using no-ip

Tags: php, sockets, noip

How can I connect via socket using DNS name from no-ip? or Is there a way to get the IP from no-ip dns name?

working

```
$cnt = socket_connect($socket,"100.100.100.100",$port);
```

but the IP is dynamic.
I need something like:

```
$cnt = socket_connect($socket, "blablabla.ddns.net",$port);
```

I´ve tried gethostbyname() but it returns the same IP for all no-ip name.

Answer (score 0):

This solution would depend on your server, but you can fallback to native operating system capabilities. For example, most Linux installs have `glibc`, allowing you to run a command like:

```
getent hosts blahblabla.ddns.net | awk '{print $1}'
```

Now, PHP functions like `exec()` and `system()` can be used to run stuff like this.

For example:

```
$command = 'getent hosts google.com | awk \'{print $1 ; exit}\'';
$ip = exec($command);
```

Then use the IP to connect to your socket.

**NOTE:** Please do not pass user provided input into this unless you want to have a bad time.

REFERENCES: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/how-can-i-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-in-a-bash-script

Comment: Hi Jeremy, it does not work because it returns the same IP for all no-ip DNS name, like the method gethostbyname() that I said above.

Comment: There's got to be a linux variant of gethostbyname() that does a normal DNS lookup -- no difference than your web browser doing it. Maybe `dig`?

Comment: @JeremyHarris `nslookup`?